# The type or namespace name 'UI' cannot be found for using System.Web.UI

Tags: asp.net

I am following the tut here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h59db326.aspx

> #
>
> Create an App_Code directory directly
>   under the root directory of your Web
>   site (also called Web application
>   root).
>   #
>
> Copy the source file for the control
>   (WelcomeLabel.cs or WelcomeLabel.vb)
>   to the App_Code directory.

But I got the error on

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControl;
```

I have tried to add System.Web as Reference but that still doesn't resolve the stuff. I can't see System.Web.UI and System.Web.UI.WebControl in the reference lists is this normal ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is check if the **System.Web** reference is in your references folder. This can be done by looking into the references folder inside your project. (Projectname**References**)

The reference **System.Web** has to be there.
Note: If it's not inside the reference folder, then you have to add it. (Right mouseclick on the *References* folder, select *Add Reference...*, tab .Net and select *System.Web*)

Now you can use all the namespaces of System.Web.